# SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "BC"."SPAREBOX": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I using oracle to calculate with some alias with CTE, but when i run it happen an error

this is my query:

```
WITH BOXCOUNT AS (                                                         
SELECT 
PRODUCT_CODE 
 , ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE)) AS FULLBOX
 , CASE WHEN SUM((TOTAL_QUANTITY - ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE))) * PACKING_STYLE) = 0 THEN 0
       WHEN SUM((TOTAL_QUANTITY - ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE))) * PACKING_STYLE) > 0 THEN 1
    END AS SPARE_BOX

FROM 
    LOG0104M 
GROUP BY 
PRODUCT_CODE)

SELECT
L04.PRODUCT_CODE
, L04.PRODUCT_NAME 
, L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY
, L04.PACKING_STYLE

, BC.FULLBOX
, BC.SPAREBOX

, SUM(BC.FULLBOX + BC.SPAREBOX) AS TOTALBOX     
FROM LOG0104M L04
JOIN BOXCOUNT BC
ON   BC.PRODUCT_CODE = L04.PRODUCT_CODE 

GROUP BY  
L04.PRODUCT_CODE
, L04.PRODUCT_NAME
, L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY
, L04.PACKING_STYLE
, BC.FULLBOX
, BC.SPAREBOX
```

this is an error:

```
SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "BC"."SPAREBOX": invalid identifier
```

Comment: Typo: You called the alias `SPARE_BOX` in the CTE, but you used `SPAREBOX` in the query below.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: oh sorry it is my mistake